# Setting up a fake admin login

Tags: php, security, xhtml

After having my Paypal account compromised I got a bit paranoid and wanted to secure everything in my sites. One of them includes renaming the admin/ page to something else, then I will put something like a honeypot to see which IP's they are coming from:

```
    <?
// honeypot 

if($_POST['username']) { 
sleep(10);

$filename = "intruders.txt"; 
$date = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
$handle = fopen($filename,"a+");
$content = "Username: $_POST[username] , Password: $_POST[password]  $date ... from $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] \n";
fwrite($handle,$content);
fclose($handle);

echo "<br/><b>Wrong username or password. Please try again</b><br/><br/>"; 

} 

?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>WHMCS - Admin alt</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id='login' action='index.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset>
<legend>WHMCS Secure alt Login</legend> 
<label for='username' >Username*:</label>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" />
<label for='password' >Password*:</label>
<input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</fieldset>
</form>
<div id="footer">Copyright &copy; <a href="http://www.whmcs.com/" target="_blank">WHMCompleteSolution</a>.  All Rights Reserved.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My only concern right now is, can this form be attacked to gain access to the site? I don't think sql injection can work here since we never used sql, nor injecting js to the output since it only outputs some fake text. After that I can't think of anything else an attacker might get wise on...

What do you think? could there be a better way to track them down?

Comment: A page that submits to itself and doesn't affect anything else on the site can't really be used to subvert the system. However, a malicious user COULD simply spam the hell out of the page and submit multi-megabyte usernames/passwords, causing you to fill up your disk.

Comment: What are you going to do even if you do track them down? Nip over to Bulgaria or wherever and arrest them? It's probably not even illegal where they operate from. And what about the next one and the next one and the .... It's annoying but not worth fussing over other than securing you site as well as you can.

Comment: This is a tough question and can't be answered by looking at that page only. Brute force is almost always possible, so you must define proper password retry counts, etc. If necessary, you should perform a detailed threat analysis and then proceed. Look at www.owasp.org.

Comment: I don't think tracking them down will do any good, assuming it's at all feasible. However, I would think about blacklisting the IPs coming to the honeypot after, say 3 login attempts. Also to make the whole thing a bit more devious, I would apply the blacklist only to the real admin page, while letting them play with the fake admin page a while longer... perhaps setting a timeout and then cutting them out altogether. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you've posted the code here, you've spoiled the surprise. If you are going to use this code in production, change the code so it won't be that easy to google.

Notes:

- `sleep(10)` - this makes your server vulnerable to a denial of service attack
- writing to a file in the current directory - if you're going to log to a file, do not log it just in a public area. You should not expose details like IP addresses to the public unless your visitors don't care about it.
- denial of service (2) due to unlimited logging - there is not flood protection nor is the input restricted
- logging of passwords - not really effective in my opinion unless you want to know where an attacker comes from (cracked email accounts, compromised database, ...)

I would avoid using a honey pot like this. Besides that not all form submissions are cracking attempts (I've seen bots submitting my forms which were "protected" with a simple text question), it may be challenging visitors with bad intentions. Do proper logging of requests and actions and let someone review your code.

Comment: Thanks for all the input, I will take down the page.